# Does anyone know anything about this bitcoin bouns cloud mining emails I am getting?

Tags: fraud

memo BOSA asara@abv.bg
Attachments
4:35 PM (4 hours ago)
to marszaleknowiny

> My name Lisa Davis, I am senior director of Bitcoin Bonus
> Evening late (the day before) you received an automatic smessage from us about the status of your wallet.
> We would like to remind you that you authorized with us 1 year ago ≈375 days ago,.
> Your account and the server capacities you have reserved have been working all year
> You have 1.48283 BTC saved in your account, which is equivalent to 29,383 at the current exchange rate.
> Please note that our company is currently changing its legal status and reorganizing into a new legal entity.
> According to our company rules, if a client does not withdraw his earned money within a year, his account can be blocked.
>
> You urgently need to activate your account and withdraw money .
>
> We can see that you have already tried to withdraw your funds and were unable to do so.
>
> Most probably, the possibility of paying by credit card is not available in your country, so we can offer you the possibility to pay by Bitcoin .
>
> Please be reminded that after 21:11:32 your account may be blockedk5iNCOi99.
>
> To withdraw funds login to personal account.
> Details, in attached to the letter file
>
> If you ignore our message
> And you will not make transfer within 23:55:121 .
> Your account will then be blocked and your funds will be zeroed.
>
> Sincerely,  bitcoin bonus
>
> More details about registration:
> Sender: 7258****9964
> Authorization code: 21985027
> P/C: 15472257731844658768581689
> TIN: 739228900547
> BIC: 2340083637959
> One attachment
> •  Scanned by Gmail

Answer (score 4):

Its spam, aiming at getting the unwary scammed. Mark it as spam and delete it. Its a variation of the old "someone died and we need to give the money to someone" scam.